# Attached schema to Meteor.users and now unable to create new users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I am trying to expand the Meteor.users collection and I've got everything working fairly well so far except for some reason with this it's not allowing me to register new users anymore. I am using the accounts-google package for login/registration, logging in with an account that's already been created works great but when I attempt to register with a new account it doesn't work and I receive the following error in my browser console:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': ReferenceError: ServiceConfiguration is not defined
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/useraccounts_core.js?e3a764dbf634d8bf2a393797c0a82e9fadef2e7a:2551:48
    at Accounts.callLoginMethod.userCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-oauth.js?8a30b216f87b515ab9b4bf5d4970a7113d0c6c2f:163:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-base.js?7dabd814506e384c709f8bf707377955f9814129:612:26
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:794:19
    at loggedInAndDataReadyCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-base.js?7dabd814506e384c709f8bf707377955f9814129:708:7)
    at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3500:12)
    at _.extend.receiveResult (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3520:10)
    at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:4625:9)
    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3365:12)
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong here? I've been playing around with it for quite a while and just cant seem to get it to work. Any help/insight is greatly appreciated.

```
Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    userProfile: {
        type: Object
    },
    'userProfile.firstName': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "First Name"
    },
    'userProfile.lastName': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Last Name"
    },
    'userProfile.birthday': {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        label: "Date of Birth"
    },
    'userProfile.contactEmail': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Contact Email"
    },      
    'userProfile.gender': {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true,
        label: "Gender"
    },
    'userProfile.country': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Country"
    },
    'userProfile.address': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Address"
    },
    'userProfile.city': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "City"
    },
    'userProfile.stateProvince': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "State/Province"
    },
    'userProfile.postalCode': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Postal Code"
    },
    'userProfile.phoneNumber': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Phone Number"
    },    

});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        // For accounts-password, either emails or username is required, but not both. It is OK to make this
        // optional here because the accounts-password package does its own validation.
        // Third-party login packages may not require either. Adjust this schema as necessary for your usage.
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        // For accounts-password, either emails or username is required, but not both. It is OK to make this
        // optional here because the accounts-password package does its own validation.
        // Third-party login packages may not require either. Adjust this schema as necessary for your usage.
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    // Make sure this services field is in your schema if you're using any of the accounts packages
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
    // Option 1: Object type
    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
    // Example:
    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
    // you will fail validation in some cases.
    roles: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // In order to avoid an 'Exception in setInterval callback' from Meteor
    heartbeat: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);

Meteor.users.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        // only allow posting if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        return !! userId;
    },

    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames) {
        // only allow updating if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        // a user can only update his own user doc and only the 'userProfile' field
        return !! userId && userId === doc._id && _.isEmpty(_.difference(fieldNames, ['userProfile'])); 
    },
});
```

Comment: Do you have the service-configuration package installed? https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/service-configuration

Comment: Yup service-configuration is installed, I've checked the "meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration" in robomongo and I can see that everything is there and the clientId / secret is all correct. Thing is when I remove the Schema file above from my project then everything works fine again, so I believe it has to have something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your standard 'new' user object does not match your schema and will fail on creation.

So, to get around this you want to reformat the output of the object provided by the `Account.onCreateUser` function:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    //format the 'user' object as you need it to be here
    // to pass your schema validation
    return user;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would you be able to give me an example of how you think I would format the schema? Ideally I am hoping to just have the account be created for the user, then the new profile information can be added via a form once the account has been created and they are signed-in. 

Also, I noticed I didn't mention in the original post, but I'm using [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) as well, in those docs there is a "Attach a Schema to Meteor.users" section which I based my schema off of.

Comment: You want to reformat the object to match your schema: implement the onCreated function and check the format of the object in debugger (it's pretty much what it is in mongo), then rewrite the object to match your schema, i.e. create an object that matches your schema and fill the fields as needed.